# Change ListView row item height size, but Scroll calculate it again

Tags: android, android-listview

I changed a row height (to 0 for hide), but ListView Scroll again calulate it !!
and me have multi scroll.

How i can fix it ? Thanks You

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide an item from the listview just remove the item from the list or arraylist which you have inflated inside the listview.

If you do not wish to remove the item then create a custom adapter for your listview and change the layout params of the respective item according to its position in the getView() method of the custom adapter.

Comment: for a listview you have to create a custom baseadapter or custom arrayadapter.